# How Do I Debug Inverted Index?

Tags: python, dictionary, set, inverted-index

Trying to create an inverted index from a subset but not getting the appropriate return values.
return value for experiment d1 should be just [0] instead I am getting a list of both experiment and studi.
When I try to clear the new list I get empty lists as a return.`enter code here`

```
subset={'d1': ['experiment','studi','wing', 'propel', 'slipstream',  'made', 'order', 'determin', 'spanwis',
'distribut','lift', 'increas',  'due','slipstream', 'differ'],'d2':['studi','high-spe','viscou', 'flow', 
'past', 'two-dimension', 'bodi','usual','necessari','consid', 'curv', 'shock', 'wave', 'emit', 'nose', 
'lead', 'studi', 'bodi','.','consequ']}

set_set =['experiment','studi']

new=[]
inv_index={}
final={}
for word in set_set:
    for key, values in subset.items():
        for value in values:
            if word == value:
                new.append(values.index(word))
                inv_index[key]=new
        final[word]=inv_index
final

###Output
#{'experiment': {'d1': [0, 1, 0, 0], 'd2': [0, 1, 0, 0]},
 #'studi': {'d1': [0, 1, 0, 0], 'd2': [0, 1, 0, 0]}}

#should be {'experiment':{'d1':[0]},'studi':{'d1':[1],'d2':[0,16]}}
#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're tracking a lot of stuff you don't need.  Also remember that `index` does not work if there are duplicates.  `index` always returns the index of the FIRST match.

This does what you ask:

```
subset={'d1': ['experiment','studi','wing', 'propel', 'slipstream',  'made', 'order', 'determin', 'spanwis',
'distribut','lift', 'increas',  'due','slipstream', 'differ'],'d2':['studi','high-spe','viscou', 'flow', 
'past', 'two-dimension', 'bodi','usual','necessari','consid', 'curv', 'shock', 'wave', 'emit', 'nose', 
'lead', 'studi', 'bodi','.','consequ']}

set_set =['experiment','studi']

final={}
for word in set_set:
    final[word] = {}
    for key, values in subset.items():
        found = [idx for idx,value in enumerate(values) if word == value]
        if found:
            final[word][key] = found
print(final)
```

Output:

```
{'experiment': {'d1': [0]}, 'studi': {'d1': [1], 'd2': [0, 16]}}
```